# Access specific form in formset without hardcoding the index

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset

Is there a way to access a specific form from an inline formset, in the template, without hardcoding the index?
I know that the usual way to iterate through a formset is to do something like:

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

But due to some details on the template (i have multiple formsets, that should be displayed side by side on a table, inside another `for`), it would be better if i could access each form by its index. I can do this by hardcoding the index, like `{{ formset.0 }}`, but since i'm iterating in the template, the ideal would be to get the form by the forloop.counter, so that i could do something like

```
{% for field in fields %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
    <td>{{ formset1.[forloop.counter0] }}</td>
    <td>{{ formset2.[forloop.counter0] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom indexing isn't possible inside template.

You can achieve the same result by creating your own filter. See the following snippet:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2740/

Comment: Cheers! I had just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771323/how-to-access-list-using-variable-indexes-in-django-templates#answer-13771503 , but your solution is even simpler!