# Jinja2 template - access variable in a tag block

Tags: jinja2

In my template I'm trying to access a variable inside a block tag as shown below. The 2nd line throws an error. How can I do this in a Jinja template?

```
{% for key, value in ratingheads.iteritems() %}
    {% for error in form.{{ value.name }}.errors %}
        <ul>
             <li>{{ error }}</li>
        <ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771323/how-to-access-list-using-variable-indexes-in-django-templates

Comment: The fact that you might be using Django is irrelevant. Jinja templates are not Django, and have different syntax and functionality.